# from php to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

i have array in php, and i need work with this array in jQuery.
What best way send array( or variable ) from php to jQuery?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) (PHP >= 5.2) is arguably the easiest way.

```
$array_js = json_encode($array);

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> my_array = ".$array_js."; </script>";
```

Comment: If you're (PHP < 5.2), I've had success with the jsonwrapper script. http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have to dynamically load it, try something like this:

```
<script>
var the_array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>
</script>
```